# How to call a method using array without object?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, slim

How can I call a method like in laravel or slim route?

Let's say I have class like this:

```
namespace App;
class App
{
    public function getApp(){
        return "App";
    }
}
```

and I want to call on this way

```
$route->get('App\App','getApp');
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do it like this?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way

```
call_user_func_array(['App\App', 'getApp'], $params_if_needed);
```

[php.net source call_user_func_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)

If you need to check if method exists, just use

```
method_exists('SomeClass','someMethod') // returns boolean
```

[php.net method_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php)

So you Router class may be next:

```
class Router
{
     public function get($class, $method)
     {
          if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'GET') {
              throw new SomeCustomNotFoundException();
          }

          if (!method_exists($class, $method)) {
              throw new SomeCustomNoMethodFoundException();
          }

          call_user_func_array([$class, $method], $_REQUEST); //with params
          // OR
          call_user_func([$class, $method]); //without params, not sure
     }
}
```

If you want to do in the more clever way, you can use [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php), it will give you information about class/method existence and also give information about method params, and which of them are required or optional.

**UPDATE:** This example expects methods to be static. For non-static you can add check, in the Router class, for class existence (class_exists($class)) and do smth like this

```
$obj = new $class();
$obj->$method(); //For methods without params
```

**UPDATE(2)** to check this out go [here](http://phptester.net/) and paste next code

```
<?php

class Router
{
     public function get($class, $method)
     {
          if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'GET') {
              throw new SomeCustomNotFoundException();
          }

          if(!class_exists($class)) {
              throw new ClassNotFoundException();
          }

          if (!method_exists($class, $method)) {
              throw new SomeCustomNoMethodFoundException();
          }

          call_user_func_array([$class, $method], $_REQUEST); //with params
          // OR
         //call_user_func([$class, $method]); //without params, not sure
     }
}

class Test
{
    public static function hello()
    {
        die("Hello World");
    }
}

$route = new Router();
$route->get('Test', 'hello');
```